# nginx + spawn fcgi + php = "No input file specified."

Tags: nginx

If fastcgi is running I get "No input file specified."
If the fastcgi is not up, I get "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable."
This is my config file:

```
   server {
 listen   80;
 server_name website.org;

  root   /home/user/public_html;

 location / {
  index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
 location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/user/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
               include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;

 }
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /home/user/public_html/50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

I've read that changing value for cgi.fix_pathinfo and cgi.force_redirect in php.ini might help but for me it didn't.

Comment: Have you checked the FGCI logs for errors?  Is $fastcgi_script_name valid?

Comment: $fastcgi_script_name  is good and im not sure if there are any fcgi logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but:
Does php have access rights to  `/home` `/home/user/` `/home/user/....`?

PS. You also can try [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/Main_Page) instead of spawn_fcgi

Answer (score 1):

Please include the following line in fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd second the php-fpm recommendation, the "No input file specified" error is well-known, and php-fpm has a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same situation of you. But I'm using php-fpm.
But my situation is a little different. I'm running the server no error.
Several days after, the browser display 'No input file specify'.
 But everything go well after restart the php-fpm .